# jQuery bind sending form twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I did a script and he are submitting forms twice. Someone can help?

PS: I need that any element can send forms

```js
$('*').bind('click', function(event) {
      if ($(this).attr('href') && $(this).attr('href') != '#') {
        .....
      } else if ($(this).attr('form-name')) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);

        var FormId = '#' + $(this).attr('form-name');

        var Target = $(this).attr('action-url');

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'html',
          url: Target,
          data: $(FormId).serialize(),
          success: function(response) {
            eval(response);
          }
        }).always(function() {
          $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: I strongly advise against binding a click event to every element on the page. That being said, the form may be firing its own submit event in addition to your click event handler. Please show your relevant HTML so that we can more easily visualize what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are submitting your form once via the `$.ajax` call, and once via the `<button>`'s default behaviour.  Add:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to the end of your `click` handler.

Also, if you want a click handler on every element on your page, I'd highly recommend looking into [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).